# Unable to connect to the remote server while trying to GetRequestStream()

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, webrequest

I have very weird issue.

I have method that called by wcf that hosted by Windows service , while the method try to do GetRequestStream() we get back an exception "**Unable to connect to the remote server**"

```
string strXMLServer = "https://xxxx.webex.com/WBXService/XMLService";

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(strXMLServer);
        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
        request.Method = "POST";
        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        string strXML = XMLmanager.createXML(User, Password, requestType, sessionKey);

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strXML);

        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        // Get the request stream.
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();    //<--- here the exception!!
        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close();
        // Get the response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

**The Weird thing is** that when I try to run this application as a stanalone ( console application) I have no problem and get no error! the Exception appear only if I call the method by the WCF !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sound like you have a similar situation to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722243/unable-to-connect-to-wcf-service-from-windows-service?answertab=votes#tab-top). Check the account your Windows Service is running under, it most likely does have not access to network resources.

Comment: The windows service running under local system

Comment: In that case, you need to run it using either as a domain account with appropriate access to make HTTP calls or as the Network Service where the machine account (usually the machine name) is in the domain and has appropriate access.